# How to handle dyanmic IE popup in watir?

Tags: ruby, watir

In our application on particular operation it proceed & open other IE instance to show entered data.
I wanted to close that IE instance 
I am unable to handle that instance
Any solution?

popup have title but it open in other instance of IE if i need to close that popup & again come to my original instance what should i do.

i also use this commands

```
browser.window(:title => "annoying popup").use do
browser.button(:id => "close").click
```

but its showing

```
1) Error:
test_1(Work_login):
NoMethodError: undefined method `window' for #<Watir::IE:0x1dae700> this error
```

Comment: What have you tried and what were the results?  How can you identify the new window, does it have a distinct title?   You need to give us a little more to work with here.

Comment: first i gave my window title as name of that annoying popup & then try to close it but its showing same error as above.. As i am trying to attach that my popup having "dynamic id" so i am unable to attach that popup ?

Comment: If you are trying to use .attach, I don't see how the error could be the same, since the error is complaining about the method named .window..   Please edit the question to reflect the latest thing you tried and the exact error..  (think of this like a bug report, you need to give us enough info to really understand what's happening, vague generalities don't help.

Answer (score 1):

```
browser.window(:how, 'what').use
```

is a method only supported by Watir-Webdriver.

If you are using Watir (which I presume since you did not include the watir-webdriver tag) then that is why you are getting the error you see regarding 'undefined method'.  You need to use

```
browser.attach(:how, 'what')
```